# Two tables with same field

Tags: database-design, table

1. QUESTION: I have QUOTATION table and SOA table
   **quotation** - table is for pending and not approve quotation.
   **SOA**- table for approve quotation.

i will just transfer the data from quotation table to soa once it is approve, the difference is in soa it has soa_account_number.

the question is, is it advisable to do this process or i just use 1 table.

2. QUESTION: I have two table with same fields

   - motor_car_quotation
   - motor_car_soa

the motor_car_quotation table is the storage of motor car that is not yet approve.
the motor_car_soa is the table for approve quotation, i will just transfer all the fields from the quotation to motor_car_soa table once it is approve.

the question is, is it advisable to do this process or i just use 1 table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely a case where you should use one table IMHO.

The entities involved are virtually identical only differing by 1 important field - that makes them very good candidates for a single table.

Have the SOA_account_number in the table and set it to `NULL` if the quote hasn't been approved and have a value set when the approval process has been successfully completed.

This simplifies your schema and all you have to do to distinguish between pending and approved quotes is to use a `WHERE` clause - i.e.

```
WHERE SOA_account_number IS (or IS NOT) NULL
```

You haven't given us the full table structure (`SHOW CREATE TABLE` My_Table\G), but I would suggest having a couple of `DATE` fields (or possibly `DATETIME`) - something like `quote_offered_date` and `quote_accepted_date`. Just a couple of thoughts.